# Iptables rules validation

Tags: perl, iptables

I have a `perl` script that generates a shell script that will later be loaded by `iptables` on a remote machine. The data input for the perl script comes from a config file, where I can specify all kind of parameters for each rule.

The problem is about validation, **How would you validate the whole set of rules without the ability of executing it?**

I have searched on CPAN and the closest solution was [IPTables::Rule](http://search.cpan.org/~phillips/IPTables-Rule-0.01/lib/IPTables/Rule.pm) but it only validates some of the restrictions when it generates the rule. I can't use IPTables::IPv4 because it interacts directly with the host iptables.

Answer (score 2):

Here is how I test rules in a sh script:

```
#!/bin/sh
/usr/sbin/iptables-restore --test < yourfileofrules
[ $? -ne 0 ] && {
    echo File does NOT syntax check
    exit 1
}
```

In perl, you'll execute the iptables-restore command in whatever way you prefer and then check for a '0' exit status for success.

**[EDIT]**
I am told this is the perl way:

```
my $cmd = "/usr/sbin/iptables-restore --test < yourfileofrules";
if (system($cmd) != 0) { die("File does NOT syntax check"); }
```

Answer (score 1):

This isn't directly achieveable. The `iptables` rules string syntax is parsed partly by `iptables(8)` and partly by the individual matching or action modules that are loaded. There's no standard way to parse the input without invoking the underlying C modules directly.

Comment: Working with ternary logic (true, false, unknown) and abstracting over unknowns may still give you certain guarantees about your ruleset. Reference: [academic paper - Semantics-Preserving Simplification of Real-World Firewall Rule Sets, Diekmann et al. Formal Methods 2015](http://www.net.in.tum.de/fileadmin/bibtex/publications/papers/fm15_Semantics-Preserving_Simplification_of_Real-World_Firewall_Rule_Sets.pdf).

Answer (score 1):

Check out [fffuu](https://github.com/diekmann/Iptables_Semantics/tree/master/haskell_tool), the fancy formal firewall universal understander. It is a static analyzer for rulesets of the iptables firewall. The tool is still under active development (as of February 2017) and not completely finished yet. However, the core is completely formally verified and thus, you can trust it.

As input, it just needs the output of `iptables-save`. For your scenario, you could generate this output on a virtual machine.

What do you want to validate?

fffuu can:

- Check spoofing protection
- Translate your firewall to a simplified version, which you can then check manually
- Visualize the access control relationship implied by your firewall over the complete IPv4 and IPv6 Address space. By default, it checks for destination ports 22 and 80.

Note that ITval has bugs, reported in [Verified iptables Firewall Analysis by Cornelius Diekmann, Julius Michaelis, Maximilian Haslbeck, and Georg Carle. In IFIP Networking 2016, Vienna, Austria, May 2016 (Section 2, paragraph 2)](http://www.net.in.tum.de/fileadmin/bibtex/publications/papers/verified_iptables_firewall_analysis.pdf).

**Disclaimer**: I'm the author of [fffuu](https://github.com/diekmann/Iptables_Semantics/tree/master/haskell_tool), my views may be biased and [fffuu](https://github.com/diekmann/Iptables_Semantics/tree/master/haskell_tool) is not perfect (yet). But hey, it's free and libre and I hope it helps. Feel free to reuse any of the code :-)

Comment: I can't help reading the name in a pronounceable way: as "fu-fu-fu" ;-)

Answer (score 0):

check the following sf.net project http://sourceforge.net/projects/itval/

Comment: Note that [link-only answers are discouraged](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/tags/link-only-answers/info), SO answers should be the end-point of a search for a solution (vs. yet another stopover of references, which tend to get stale over time). Please consider adding a stand-alone synopsis here, keeping the link as a reference.